# Oracle return table from function in package

Tags: sql, database, oracle

How can I return a Table from a sql package function without using a cursor ?

Comment: I usually see people use **pipelined functions** for this. But also see the first 2 links in this article for simpler kinds of table functions. https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/pipelined-table-functions

Answer (score 0):

I usually like to implement the pipelined function with all objects inside the package.

**This is the result query:**

```
select *
from table(pkg_example_pipeline.F_PIPELINE_EXEMPLE(0));
```

**The package:**

```
create or replace PACKAGE pkg_example_pipeline IS

-- *********** TYPES
TYPE TYPE_EXEMPLE is record (
    id                      NUMBER(10,0),
    name                    VARCHAR2(100),
    date_test               DATE
);

TYPE v_table_exemple is table of TYPE_EXEMPLE;
-- *********** 

-- *********** PIPELINE FUNCTIONS
FUNCTION F_PIPELINE_EXEMPLE (pId NUMBER)
RETURN v_table_exemple  pipelined;

END; --PACKAGE SPEC
/

create or replace PACKAGE BODY pkg_example_pipeline
IS
-- ***********  CURSORs 
/**
* Just if you need 
**/

CURSOR cr_exemple
IS
 SELECT 0 id, 'name' name, sysdate date_test 
 from dual;

-- ***********  

-- *********** PIPELINE FUNCTIONS
--POSICAO DIARIA
FUNCTION F_PIPELINE_EXEMPLE (pId NUMBER)
RETURN v_table_exemple  pipelined
IS                  
    row_exemple TYPE_EXEMPLE;

BEGIN

   FOR reg_exemple IN  (SELECT 0 id, 'name' name, sysdate date_test from dual) LOOP
        BEGIN
            row_exemple.id        := reg_exemple.id;
            row_exemple.name      := reg_exemple.name;
            row_exemple.date_test := reg_exemple.date_test;

            pipe row (row_exemple);

        EXCEPTION
        WHEN others THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('error: ' || sqlerrm);
            row_exemple.name := 'error: ' || sqlerrm;
            pipe row (row_exemple);
        END;

   END LOOP;



EXCEPTION
WHEN others THEN
     ROLLBACK;
END;

-- *********** 
END; --PKG BOBY
```